# SQL - SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id_user IN SUBQUERY?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to select all posts posted by the users listed in my SUBQUERY - SUBQUERY is a table with only one column - user IDs. The purpose is to get all posts of user's "friends"

I have a misty memory that you can use `IN` on `SELECT`
but the `SELECT`'s result can only be *one column* only - **am I right**?

So this query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id_user 
IN (SELECT id_friend as id_user FROM friends WHERE id_user=:some_id_user)
```

**Can it be done?** If so, is there a **more efficient way?**

BTW: I am using MySQL

Comment: Your query is fine. And seems pretty efficient as well.

Comment: Well it is nice that is seems :)), but have you actually tested it in comparsion to other possibilities - **are there even any other possibilites?**

Comment: None that I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes in between `JOIN` and `subquery`, `JOIN` is faster. Though it depends on scenario, in this case, `JOIN` would be better.

Use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    posts P
INNER JOIN 
    friends F ON P.id_user = F.id_friend 
WHERE F.id_user  = :some_id_user
```

See this for more info : [Stackoverflow :: Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)

Comment: NB - There are a number of unexpected cases in DB2 when `WHERE EXISTS(...)` is faster.

Comment: @Hogan : what is DB2 ?

Comment: @Hogan and #hsuk - and what if the SUBQUERY is  getting IDs from different tables? You know like there are some other connections than friends?

Comment: join those tables too

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with an in statement as you describe or an inner join.  For simple query like this I would expect the performance to be the same.

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE id_user IN (SELECT id_friend FROM friends WHERE id_user=:some_id_user)
```

OR (similar to your query)

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts P
JOIN friends F ON P.id_user = F.id_friend AND  F.id_user = :some_id_user
```

Comment: @hsuk - did not, I beat you by **ONE MINUTE** (check the timestamps!) :D

Comment: @hsuk - my answered lines are 1 min different.

Comment: go to my profile and browse recent questions, u will find unanswered tsql questions over der :) Leave these basic questions for we amateurs :)

Comment: @hsuk - I checked -- all your questions already have all the answers I know... I guess you are stuck with me harassing you.  But I did give you a +1 even if I was first by timestamp.